# Storyboard Not Stopping When Using Interaction DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use an interaction data trigger to start a storyboard. The problem is the storyboard never stops. Is there a way to have it stop after it runs once?

My storyboard:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="DoorCloseStoryboard" SpeedRatio="2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" 
                RepeatBehavior="1x" FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetName="ChargeDoorImage">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/Mesabi.MixVision.Client.Wpf;component/Resources/Mixer/2/ChargeDoor/CDO.png"/>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/Mesabi.MixVision.Client.Wpf;component/Resources/Mixer/2/ChargeDoor/CDMid.png"/>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/Mesabi.MixVision.Client.Wpf;component/Resources/Mixer/2/ChargeDoor/CDC.png"/>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

My trigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MixerInfo.IsInAuto}" Value="true">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource DoorCloseStoryboard}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: The only reason i can think of is that your binding MixerInfo.IsInAuto is causing the storyboard to begin each time it changes.

Comment: @BelahceneBenzaraTahar That led me in the direction to solving the problem. It wasn't that it was changing each time, but I was calling property notify change each time.